# Error in PHPMyAdmin #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm importing a MySql database into `phpmyadmin` and it's giving me this error:

> 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

SQL Query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `global_config` (
  `id` int(10) primary key NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sitename` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `siteurl` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `admin_email` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `mail_from` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `smtp_from` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `smtp_pass` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `app_enabled` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `paypal_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `paypal_sandbox` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `fb_profile_upload` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fb_page_upload` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `twitter_upload` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `instagram_upload` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pinterest_upload` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `youtube_upload` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `global_message` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `referer_prize` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `fb_verified_likes` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tw_verified_followers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `in_verified_followers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pin_verified_followers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `yt_verified_subscribers` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `yt_verified_views` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `min_payout_amount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `per_ads_payout` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credit_system` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `enable_cash_payout` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Well, you're trying to put `AUTO_INCREMENT` on pretty much every field and the message tells the truth, you can only have _one_ in a single table.

Comment: What don't you understand?  `AUTO_INCREMENT` is only allowed on one field and that should be the primary key.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. Thank you